# ion-datetime problem with value changing when max and min are specified

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using ion-datetime in my project, here is some info about Ionic version:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2
```

And here is a sample of my ion-datetime:

```
 <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MM YYYY" min="{{minDate}}" max=" {{maxDate}}"
        [(ngModel)]="model"
        cancelText="{{'cancel' | translate}}"
        doneText="{{'done' | translate}}"></ion-datetime>
```

The max value is always set to current date and min value is set to current date to half a year back:

```
this.maxDate=moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //e.g. maxDate=10.05.2021
this.minDate=moment().subtract(6, 'month')  //e.g. minDate=01.11.2020
      .startOf('month')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

When the user opened the DateTime field on UI, everything displayed correctly:

[image: beforechange]

However, the user changed the year to 2020 the day and the month stays on the previous value:

[image: afterfirstchange]

After returning with year to previous 2021 year and then changing once more to 2020 the day and month are updating:

[image: aftersecondchange]

In console I have an error, but user can scroll it without any problems and the selected value is processed later in app:

```
[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

How can I fix the above error and fix this dateTime picker issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug from the Ionic V3 `ion-datetime` component, and I see that the issue never was fixed.

**Expected behavior:**
When the user changes a date value from the picker column, the *ionChange* event always must be fired to update the rest of the picker columns.

**Current behavior:** When the user changes a date value from the picker column, *then ionChange event is not fired the first time*.

**Solution:** Open the file `node_modules/ionic-angular/components/picker/picker-column.js` and search line 297. You will see this:

```
297 if (emitChange) {
298   if (this.lastIndex === undefined) {
299     // have not set a last index yet
300     this.lastIndex = this.col.selectedIndex;
301   }
302   else if (this.lastIndex !== this.col.selectedIndex) {
...
```

Remove lines 298, 299, 300 and 301. Remove the `else` property from line 302 as well and save the file.

The **edited file** must look like this:

```
297 if (emitChange) {
298   if (this.lastIndex !== this.col.selectedIndex) {
...
```

Now, the *ionChange* event will also be fired the first time that some picker column is modified.

**Remember** that you modify the `picker-column.js` file directly from your `node_modules`, so your changes will disappear for new installations.

In my case, I use Docker and an entry point to solve this scenario. I overwrite the file after the npm install is done. This is only an idea ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's really good workaround, but I have hope, the Ionic team will fix it or even use your fix :)

Comment: Hey chebad, thanks to you.

Unfortunately, the issue is there since 2017, and the team will not resolve it for Ionic v3.

I recommend using this approach as I did in the past :)